# AWS Lambda Function Shell Command not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function as part of a custom deployment stack. It calls `/opt/awscli/aws s3 s3//<bucket name> /tmp/tmpfolder/`

But it returns with a error 127. Presumably, because it can't find /opt/awscli/aws.

This is the code that errors:

```
def aws_command(*args):
    aws="/opt/awscli/aws" # from AwsCliLayer
    logger.info("| aws %s" % ' '.join(args))
    subprocess.check_call([aws] + list(args))
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] 2022-12-13T06:08:25.547Z    7a8c5bee-a4ec-4ef0-aa53-6ebe2496f89d    Command '['/opt/awscli/aws', 's3', 'cp', 's3://<bucket_name>/<80cd38...rest_of_zip>.zip', '/tmp/tmpblg17gcs/006ca603-6934-431e-9a96-0bd41b25d465']' returned non-zero exit status 127.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 103, in handler
    s3_deploy(s3_source_zips, s3_dest, user_metadata, system_metadata, prune)
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 130, in s3_deploy
    aws_command("s3", "cp", s3_source_zip, archive)
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 188, in aws_command
    subprocess.check_call([aws] + list(args))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/awscli/aws', 's3', 'cp', 's3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-403230261384-us-west-2/80cd38c81cb1261c29a32510bb6fafd2cfbe110c40d6ab17cb9e78fc2b78202b.zip', '/tmp/tmpblg17gcs/006ca603-6934-431e-9a96-0bd41b25d465']' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make sure /opt/awscli/aws it where it should be found by lambda function? Is there a way to manually install onto the ec2 instance?

Comment: The AWS CLI is not installed in the default Lambda execution environment.  To use it, you'll either need to include it in a custom layer, or as part of your deployment package.  (And note, this has nothing to do with EC2).  Honestly though, you'll be much better off using boto3 to communicate with AWS.

Comment: See [downloading files](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html).

Comment: "Honestly though, you'll be much better off using boto3 to communicate with AWS." Absolutely true.  Also, boto3 is available in the lambdas by default so you don't even have to build a package